# String not convertible to DictionaryIndex<String, AnyObject>

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that loops through an array that contains either Strings or Dictionaries and sets values for a new Dictionary of type `[String:AnyObject]`, using values from the original array as keys. `sections` is an array of custom `Section` objects and its method `getValue` always returns a `String`.

```
func getSectionVariables() -> [String:AnyObject] {
    var variables = [String:AnyObject]()

    for section in sections {
        if let name = section.name as? String {
            variables[name] = section.getValue()
        } else if let name = section.name as? [String:String] {
            for (k, v) in name {
                if variables[k] == nil {
                    variables[k] = [String:String]()
                }

                if var dict = variables[k] as? [String:String] {
                    dict[v] = section.getValue() //This works, but of course copies variables by value and doesn't set variables[k] 
                }

                (variables[k] as? [String:String])![v] = section.getValue() //Can't get this line to compile
            }
        }
    }

    return variables
}
```

If I try to cast `variables[k]` as a `[String:String]`, the compiler insists that `String is not convertible to DictionaryIndex<String, AnyObject>`. I'm not sure why downcasting isn't working and why the compiler thinks I'm trying to use the alternate dictionary subscript syntax.

Note that this project is in Swift 1.1.

Comment: normally when i get these i change my code to use temp variables. I would first do `var tmp = variables[k] as? [String:String]` then I would do `tmp[v] = section.getValue()`. Then you can break down where the error is coming from.

Comment: That's what I did right above in `if var dict = variables[k] as? [String:String] {` and it works fine.

Comment: I was not able to find a document reference for this, but my experience is that if you do just `(x as? Type)` this is a `let` binding. If you want a `var` binding (so that you can mutate it) you need to assign to a `var` property, as I mentioned.

Comment: So basically, you're saying since x as? Type is a let binding there's no way to downcast a dictionary and then set a variable in it?

Comment: I'm saying you cannot downcast and assign. For example, if i'm using a simple String, the following is an error: `(y as? String) = str`. You have a comment in your `if` statement that is surprising to me. I would have expected the update to work because you should have a reference to the dictionary stored at `variables[k]`.

Comment: it's not a reference though because it's a dictionary and dictionaries copy by value. Anyway, sum up what you've said in comments and post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem is that a "cast expression" does not yield an "l-value" and therefore cannot be assigned to. For example, consider the following simplified version of the code:

```
var x = "initial"
var y : AnyObject? = x
(y as? String) = "change"
```

You will get an error on the last line, because you cannot assign to a "cast expression".